# Fogbugz API Creating a Milestone

Tags: javascript, fogbugz, fogbugz-api

According to the [API Documentation](http://help.fogcreek.com/8202/xml-api?se_found=1#Creating), you can create a new milestone using the command newFixFor.

I'm using the command, and it returns the created milestone successfully. However, when I go into fogbugz and view the milestone under projects, it is unassignable. I am passing in the fAssignable=true into the url so I don't understand why the milestones end up being unassignable.

Here is the query string

```
'cmd=newFixFor&fAssignable=true&ixProject=' + projectId + '&sFixFor=' +  '\"' + milestoneName + '\"'
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `fAssignable=1`, not `fAssignable=true`.